# Nonsense error in laravel [Syntax error: unexpected token '$table'PHP] what is the problem?

Tags: php, laravel, visual-studio-code, syntax-error

[image]

I gave my table name to the models file I created and it gave syntax error

> Syntax error: unexpected token '$table'

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Comment: It's right that there is an error. I'd have expected you should get something like `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected variable "$table", expecting "function" or "const"` normally, but the error you've got isn't wrong. You can't declare just a bare variable in a class. Either make it a property, or put it inside a function or constructor, as needed.

Answer (score 2):

the `$table` *variable* is a [class property](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php), and class properties needs to be defined with their [visibility](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php) as a prefix ( `public`, `protected` or `private` ).

In this particular case, the `$table` property is already define on the `Model`, so we know it's visibility, it's `protected`.

```php
class YourModel extends Model {
  protected $table = "your table";
}
```

Comment: thanks problem solved but why do we need to do this?

Comment: It's needed to define how your class property can be access. Previously, leaving the visibility out would default to "public", however, it's bad practice to omit it. Now, php doesn't even let you omit the visibility.

Comment: I got it, thank you, sir.

Answer (score 0):

We have to define the access modifier for that class property.

For table use :- `protected $table = "users"`

You may define the primary key field name for your table  so model will known for that.

```
protected $primaryKey = "code";
```

If you model has non-integer data type primary key field then you have to define these below in model
Example : In you model has code is primary key so according to it is string datatype so you have define that as given below example.

```
protected $keyType = 'string';
```